# How is $[P \text{ AND } (Q \text{ OR } R)] \text{ IFF } [(P \text{ AND } Q) \text{ OR } (P \text{ AND } R)]$ valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The image below was taken from some [reading materials](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap01.pdf) in a public course on the mathematics of computer science. The text states that the proposition *[P AND (Q OR R)] IFF [(P AND Q) OR (P AND R)]* is valid.

**Question:  how is this formula 'valid' when clearly it evaluates to False in some of the cases (ex. when P,Q,R are all False)?**

[image]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun: That won't help him much here, given that the notation in his source uses words rather than symbols for the connectives _anyway_.

Comment: This question indicates one reason as to why you want to identify the principal connective of a formula.  Namely, it helps you figure out whether or not you have computed the right formula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The truth table in your image does not have a column for the value of the entire formula -- only for the subformula on each side of the "IFF".

Since those two columns have the *same* pattern of T and F, a column for the entire formula would have T all the way.

Comment: Indeed, if the final column would have been included with header $$\big(P\land (Q\lor R)\big) \leftrightarrow \big((P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)\big)$$  the column would contain, below that "header" T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, because whenever the truth values match on the left and right of $\leftrightarrow$ match under any truth value assignment to the variables, then  the biconditional is true. And so indeed, the proposition you are asking about, sean, is indeed a tautology.  You just missed the most crucial column.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the last two columns in the table, they are identical, aren't they?

Hence

$$P \land (Q \lor R)$$

and

$$(P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$$

are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The formula in question involves "iff." The statement "A iff B" evaluates to true when A and B are either both true or both false. The truth table shows that the A and B in question are always either both true or both false.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: how is this formula 'valid' when clearly it evaluates to False in some of the cases (ex. when P,Q,R are all False)?

$\def\too{\leftrightarrow}$Not just *some* cases, the clauses evaluate to false in the **same** cases.   You see that $P\land(Q\lor R)$ is false is *exactly* when $(P\land Q)\lor (P\land R)$ is false.   Likewise for all true cases.

In all cases $P\land (Q\lor R)$ and $(P\land Q)\lor(P\land R)$ have the *same* truth value.   They are equivalent.   Then $(P\land (Q\lor R))\too((P\land Q)\lor(P\land R))$ is alwas true because that is what the biconditional means.